# how to get last 30days in epoch

Tags: python, datetime, time, epoch

I am using [Pendo's API](https://developers.pendo.io/docs/?python#get-visitor-history-for-a-time-period) to gather user visitor data.

The API works on epoch when it comes to timing. I am trying to get the last 30days...I can get the current time using the `time` module like `time.time()`

I have tried to search through this site: 
https://www.epochconverter.com/timestamp-list

But to get the last 30 days, it's from the date I am viewing the site. From what I understand the epoch number would always change.

Any ideas on how to get the past 30days every time the request is run?

Comment: It's not clear what your problem is. Are you trying to ask how to subtract 30 days from the current time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I unsderstood answer correctly, that's what you need:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
last_30_days=[int((datetime.now() - timedelta(days=i)).timestamp()) for i in range(30)]
```

---

**Upd.** I've checked API referenced in question and it requires just `starttime` option **in miliseconds**. You just need to subtract 30 days from current time. Code:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
thirty_days_ago = int((datetime.now() - timedelta(days=30)).timestamp() * 1000)
```

Answer (score 2):

Epoc time is just (normally) the number of seconds since 00:00 Jan 1st 1970.

So if you know what the current epoc time is you can just minus 2592000 (60 * 60 * 24 * 30) seconds from that value to get you the time 30days pervious.